# How to use socket.io to partially refresh page after server side code runs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io to perform a simple operation in my solution built using nodejs (express). The objective is to ask the user to upload a file, and when the upload operation completes, display the message "file uploaded" on the screen without refreshing the page. To do this, I am using the following code:

Server side:

```
app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
  // Upload file stuff here...
    mv(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('sock connected');
        socket.emit('uploaded', {msg: 'File ' + files.filetoupload.name + 'uploaded to server'});
      });
      console.log('moved file');     
      res.sendFile(index);
    });
  });
});
```

And Client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
      socket.on('uploaded', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
     $('#messagebox').html(data.msg);
    });
  </script>
```

where messagebox is the originally empty div in which I want to display the message.

This code doesn't work. The `io.on('connection'...` code never gets called. I did move this code outside the app route with only a console.log statement to test that it works and it did. My assumption is that I am using the wrong event ('connection') here. But I cannot find anything in the documentation that allows me to create a socket object using a custom event. Can someone help me out?

If there is another way to implement a server code driven partial refresh of the client page (i.e. not using socket), I am open to learning that too. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to emit file on another user

Comment: Not really... I just want to send a message to the client page from the server code to update the div

Comment: if you are using http API , then you will get response against the upload API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I figured it out shortly after posting this question (even though I had been trying for days before this).

Basically, I needed to create a socket object once (outside of all routes), and then use that object to create custom events within routes. So my working server side code (with no changes on client) now looks like this.

```
var socket = io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  return socket;  
});

app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
  //upload file stuff here
    mv(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      socket.emit('uploaded', {msg : 'File ' + files.filetoupload.name + ' uploaded to server'});
      });    
    });
  });
```